# MikTex installation problem in windows 7

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I have problem in installing MiKTeX in my laptop. It is showing Error like this:-

```
loading lightweight database...
initexmf "--common-install=G:\New folder (4)" --set-config-value=[Core]SharedSetup=1 --admin "--log-file=G:\New folder (4)\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose:
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (initexmf).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
  source line: 156
  message: The executed process did not succeed.
  info: fileName="G:\New folder (4)\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1"
```

Please Someone help me how to fix it.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Did you update in admin and user mode? Do you realy need the folder `New folder (4)`? Better use no blank or `()` in folder and file names ... Please explain better what you did!